Example of a (true) statement in PA which cannot be proved in PA and cannot be proved in ZFC?
I'm aware of a number of statements (for example, Con(PA), and those given by Goodstein's theorem and the Paris–Harrington theorem) which are stateable in Peano Arithmetic (PA), but not provable within PA. Each of these is provable in ZFC. Is there an example of a statement in PA which is not provable both in PA and  in ZFC?

Con(ZFC) is a statement in arithmetic too.

if an arithmetic statement cannot be proven in ZFC, then it cannot be proven in PA either since ZFC is strictly more powerful than PA (the natural numbers of any model of ZFC is a model of PA). Con(ZFC) is an arithmetic statement ("there exists a Godel number encoding a proof of $1 = 0$") that cannot be proven in ZFC from Godel's incompleteness theorem and hence cannot be proven in PA either

As for finite combinatorial statements (i.e. things like Goodstein and PH that have some kind of extra-logical motivation), there are the results on Laver tables that can be proved with very strong large cardinal axioms. But on the other hand, unlike with Goodstein/PH in PA, it's not known (or even really strongly suspected) that they are not provable in ZFC without large cardinals... it's an open question.

Thank you for these examples! I'm embarrassed I didn't think of Con(ZFC)

On the logical side, there’s also the question of the halting of certain algorithms/ busy beaver problem for which some relatively small explicit examples have been obtained. These are closely related to Con(ZFC) though.

How would we express the halting of an algorithm in PA?

@OllieTaylor Similarly to how we need to code logic/proofs into arithmetic to express Con(ZFC) (or Con(PA) for that matter) we need to code computability. For instance, we can use Turing machines, and devise some coding for the transition function and configurations (and some mechanism for coding finite sequences, e.g. the beta function).  Then we say “there is a finite sequence of configurations such that the first is the initial one and the last is a halting configuration and each successive configuration follows from the last via (some explicit transition function).”

You presumably meant to ask for an unprovable (in ZFC and therefore in PA) but true statement. Otherwise, $0=1$ is an easy example.

@AndreasBlass You're right. I've edited the question.

You can write explicit polynomials with integer coefficiens (albeit in many variables, 20 something or so) which ZFC cannot prove that they have a root in the algebraic closure of the rational numbers, something that PA is more than capable discussing.
